# Error while trying to run the Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I get the following error when I run my Eclipse plugin, it was working fine and not it's not even running .. It says that the 'Activator' class is not find

Here is the exact error

```
> !SESSION 2013-06-14 16:41:34.482
> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200 java.version=1.6.0_45 java.vendor=Apple
> Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
> Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide Command-line
> arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -data
> /Users/home/Documents/workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev
> file:/Users/home/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse
> Application/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64
> -consoleLog
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2013-06-14 16:41:40.698
> !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous
> session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-06-14 16:41:46.963 !MESSAGE
> System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
> local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
> value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-14 16:41:48.397 !MESSAGE Unable to
> find Action Set: TrialProject.actionSet
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-14 16:41:48.398 !MESSAGE Unable to
> find Action Set: Bachelor.actionSet
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-14 16:41:48.398 !MESSAGE Unable to
> find Action Set: Bachelor.workbenchActionSet
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-14 16:41:51.717 !MESSAGE Unable to
> create part
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.filebuffers 4 0 2013-06-14 16:41:51.719
> !MESSAGE The file does not exist. !STACK 1
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The file does not exist.  at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:237)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:112)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:559)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:978)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1242)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4222)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1480)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2584)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2557)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1395)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3209)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1667)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3227)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3254)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:360)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:301)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:861)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:841)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:113)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:242)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:629)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1115)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:520)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:505)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:74)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:629)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:644)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:987)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)  at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414) !SUBENTRY 1
> org.eclipse.core.filebuffers 4 0 2013-06-14 16:41:51.721 !MESSAGE The
> file does not exist.
```

Comment: What eclipse plugin? There are at least dozens.

Comment: What do you mean by which Eclipse plugin ?

Comment: I'm creating a menu that has 2 menu items Compile and Run and I'm trying to run Java code in German

Comment: I mean which plugin are you trying to run?  Your question title is "Error while trying to run the Eclipse plugin"

Comment: The plugin I developed .. I can't understand the question

Comment: That makes two of us.  I can't understand your question either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though you created a file via an editor, then closed the workspace without saving the file.  Before bringing up the workspace again, the file was deleted (or perhaps was never saved) and the editor is having problems because the file it was working on is no longer there.